# I can't use pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

#### Abstract

I have installed pyinstaller.

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

This is probably a successful installation.
When I ran the same command again, this is what I got.
Areas marked in black are personal information.

```
WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail in a future version of pip.
Please see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the underlying issue.
To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m pip' instead of running pip directly.
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: pyinstaller in c:\users\████\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (4.10)
Requirement already satisfied: altgraph in c:\users\████\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (0.17.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyinstaller-hooks-contrib>=2020.6 in c:\users\████\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (2022.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (40.6.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pefile>=2017.8.1 in c:\users\████\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (2022.5.30)
Requirement already satisfied: pywin32-ctypes>=0.2.0 in c:\users\████\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: importlib-metadata in c:\users\████\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (4.8.3)
Requirement already satisfied: future in c:\users\████\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from pefile>=2017.8.1->pyinstaller) (0.18.2)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions>=3.6.4 in c:\users\████\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from importlib-metadata->pyinstaller) (4.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: zipp>=0.5 in c:\users\████\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from importlib-metadata->pyinstaller) (3.6.0)
```

And when I finally tried to exe the python application, it failed.

#### What I tried

First, we typed the following command.

```
C:\Program Files\Python36>pyinstaller testexe.py --onefile
```

It then returned the following

```
'pyinstaller' is not recognized as an internal or external command, an
It is not recognized as an operable program or batch file.

(Original)
'pyinstaller' は、内部コマンドまたは外部コマンド、
操作可能なプログラムまたはバッチ ファイルとして認識されていません。
```

I followed without fail and typed the following commands.

```
C:\Program Files\Python36>py -m PyInstaller testexe.py --onefile --windowed
```

It then returned the following

```
Unable to create process using 'C:\Users\████\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe  -m PyInstaller testexe.py --onefile --windowed': ??????????????????
```

#### supplementary information

Python 3.6.1

Comment: there is something funky with your python installation of your pyinstaller instillation... try removing and reinstalling both

Answer (score 0):

I prefer you try this command:

```
$ python -m pip install pyinstaller
```

Comment: I ran ```python -m pip install pyinstaller``.The same results shown in the question were obtained.